# Django - reverse_lazy & multiple parameters

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I stuck in the redirect url after adding a new object.
I have a simple class bassed create method and form.

urls.py:

```
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('<int:branch_id>/<int:doc_type_id>/', views.documents, name='documents'),
path('<int:branch_id>/<int:doc_type_id>/add', testForm.as_view(), name='document_add'),
path('<int:branch_id>/<int:doc_type_id>/<int:pk>', detailsView.as_view(), name='details_view'),
```

form.py:

```
class TestDocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
class testForm(FormView):
    template_name = "template/add.html"
    form_class = TestDocumentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app:home')
```

And this works perfectly.

But I don,t know how to change a success_url based on reverse_lazy and arguments in the class-based function. I need this to redirect to the details page after clicking the save button.

In the HTML code, I know how to do this.

I tried using this solution (i.a. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905219), so in the testForm function I commented the sussec_url field, I added something like this ():

```
def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
    reverse_lazy('archive:details_view')
    params = urlencode({'branch_id': self.object.branch.id,
                         ...})
    ...
```

And I got the error: **'testForm' object has no attribute 'object'**.

I tried many solutions but I can't redirect the page with multiple.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You may need to use `DetailView` instead of `FormView`

Comment: Use `CreateView`, the created object is made available as `self.object` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView.object